# how to bind custom commands to keys in existing mode map?

Tags: major-mode, customize, functions, interactive

I wrote some extra commands for Python mode: `python-insert-quote` and `python-insert-double-quote`. I want to have these commands be available in the minibuffer when `python-mode` is active. How can I add these custom functions into python-mode without write a new mode?

I was thinking it might be nice to keep these additional functions saved in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/extra-python.el`

I'm not sure how hooks work or if this would be the right time to use hooks. When I look at [hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html), It says that hooks are used to change the behavior of a mode, giving this example:

> `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)`

The example would seem antithetical to what I'm trying to do. I just what the functions to be callable form the mini-buffer only when in python-mode, not to be called when the mode is launched.

---

GNU Emacs 26.1

saved in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/extra-python.el`

```lisp
(defun python-insert-quote ()
  "Inesert python single quote"
  (interactive)
  (let ((myline (thing-at-point 'line)))
    (while (string-match "\\([^ ].*\\)" myline )
      ;; remove line
      (kill-whole-line)
      ;; add better line
      (insert (concat "'" (match-string 0 myline) "'" "
"))
      ;; fix indent
      (forward-line -1)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (indent-for-tab-command)
      (error ""))))         ;(break) the equivalent

(defun python-insert-double-quote ()
  "Inesert python double quote"
  (interactive)
  (let ((myline (thing-at-point 'line)))
    (while (string-match "\\([^ ].*\\)" myline )
      ;; remove line
      (kill-whole-line)
      ;; add better line
      (insert (concat "\"" (match-string 0 myline) "\"" "
"))
      ;; fix indent
      (forward-line -1)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (indent-for-tab-command)
      (error ""))))         ;(break) the equivalent

(provide 'extra-python)
```

saved in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```lisp
;; Add commands to python mode
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (define-key python-mode-map [f6] 'python-insert-quote)
  (define-key python-mode-map [f5] 'python-insert-double-quote)))
```

Comment: The typical way this is done is by assigning them to keyboard shortcuts of the given major mode; e.g., `(define-key python-mode-map [f5] 'python-insert-quote)` and you store your custom functions wherever floats your float.

Comment: @lawlist "floats your float" Love it. Funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way this is done is by assigning the custom commands to keyboard shortcuts of a given major-mode; e.g.,

add to your Emacs init file

```lisp
;; Add commands to python mode
(require 'extra-python)
```

and then either

```lisp
(eval-after-load "python-mode" '(progn
  (define-key python-mode-map [f5] 'python-insert-quote)
  (define-key python-mode-map [f6] 'python-insert-double-quote))
```

or

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (define-key python-mode-map [f5] 'python-insert-quote)
  (define-key python-mode-map [f6] 'python-insert-double-quote)))
```

One can store his/her custom commands wherever it makes sense in the opinion of the user.  At the very bottom of `extra-python.el`, you can insert a statement `(provide 'extra-python)` and then ensure that the `~/.emacs.d/lisp/` directory has been added to the `load-path`.

If the function definitions have been loaded and are `interactive` (they are commands), a user can always type:

```
M-x NAME-OF-COMMAND
```

Comment: I tried the example, but I keep getting back `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, python-insert-double-quote`

Comment: You need to add the statement `(interactive)` to anything you intend to use with a keyboard shortcut or with `M-x ...`; e.g., `(defun python-insert-double-quote () "Doc-string" (interactive) ... BODY...)`  And, when you get more advanced, you may wish to add interactive codes ....

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem. I added my files to the question for you to take a look at. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to add `(require 'extra-python)` before `(add-hook ...`